# Ktor raw sockets read channel read nothing right after connection established

Tags: sockets, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, ktor

I'm trying to connect to IMAP server with Ktor raw sockets

```
@KtorExperimentalAPI
    override suspend fun start(host: SocketAddress) {
        socket = aSocket(ActorSelectorManager(Dispatchers.IO)).tcp().connect(host).tls(Dispatchers.IO)
        writeChannel = socket.openWriteChannel()
        readChannel = socket.openReadChannel()
        val handshakeResponse = ByteArray(readChannel.availableForRead)
        readChannel.readAvailable(handshakeResponse)
        val handshake = String(handshakeResponse)
        println(handshake)
    }
```

After this connection I excpect that I'll get IMAP server response like this

```
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE  SPECIAL-USE LITERAL+ AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN] Dovecot ready.
```

And then I send IMAP commands to login to my mailbox

```
  @KtorExperimentalAPI
    override suspend fun command(command: String): String {
        writeChannel.write("$command\r\n".also { print(it) })
        val response = ByteArray(readChannel.availableForRead)
        readChannel.readAvailable(response)
        val responseString = String(response)
        println(responseString)
        return responseString
    }
```

So my output should be like this

```
 * OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE  SPECIAL-USE LITERAL+ AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN] Dovecot ready.
S1 LOGIN email pass
S1 OK Logged in
```

But for some reason, the output looks like these commands are executed in parallel threads

```
S1 LOGIN email pass
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE  SPECIAL-USE LITERAL+ AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN] Dovecot ready.
```

And my coroutine is blocked at write/read channels because Ktor use randezvous channels and I can't write to channel until I read output

My main code looks like this

```
 fun run() {
        val store = IMAPStore()
        runBlocking(coroutineContext) {
                //connect with tls (suspend function)
                store.install()
                //send login command (suspend function)
                store.login()
        }
    }
```

I probably don’t quite understand how the connection through tls works and how the channels work. Maybe I'm starting coroutines wrong.

In this sample code the same logic works perfectly

```
fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        val socket =
            aSocket(ActorSelectorManager(Dispatchers.IO)).tcp().connect(host)
                .tls(Dispatchers.IO)
        val w = socket.openWriteChannel(autoFlush = false)
        val r = socket.openReadChannel()
        r.readUTF8LineTo(System.out)
        w.write("$TAG${tagCounter++} LOGIN email password\r\n")
        r.readUTF8LineTo(System.out)
    }
```

Can someone understand and explain this behavior?